# App is crashing due to GeoView.StartRendering () System.InvalidOperationException: Device not initialized in xamarin.forms with android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

when navigating to mappage an appcrash happend and its appcenter log showing as GeoView.StartRendering () System.InvalidOperationException: Device not initialized. this issue happening rarely with android devices.please help to resolve this issue.

> GeoView.StartRendering ()
> RenderingThread.OnResume ()
> ISurfaceTextureListener.OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged (Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height)
> TextureView+ISurfaceTextureListenerInvoker.n_OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged_Landroid_graphics_SurfaceTexture_II (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_surface, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height)
> (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.181(intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Have you tried the other emulators or the physical devices？It seems something wrong on your test device.

Comment: Is this an old device? Try adding `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />` to the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure the device meets the hardware requirements.